# How to write a custom fetch method for the FilePond file uploader?

Tags: javascript, filepond

I've got an issue with how should I deal with the `load()` function when I'm using a custom `fetch` method of FilePond. The [documentation](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#fetch-1) requires the file object to be passed to the `load()` method but I don't know how to get that. I tried passing `null` instead, but it throws an error: This is the code:

```
server: {
    fetch: (url, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
        
        progress(true, 0, 1024);

        load(file);

        return {
            abort: () => {
                abort();
            },
        };
    },
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my FilePond, when I want to fetch files from the server to the FilePond.

```
load: async (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
            let file = files.find(el => el.file == source)
            var myRequest = new Request(source);
            fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
              response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
                load(myBlob);
              });
            });
```